# Can't connect to Google Latitude API in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create an application in Apps Script that would fetch my Latitude Location History. For some reason, even if provided with all the URIs and tokens that seem to be required for OAuth to work, I always get an "Unexpected error" on the line that triggers "UrlFetchApp". What is the proper OAuth configuration that would get Latitude API to work in Apps Script?

here's the code:

```
function latitude(){
 var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("latitude");
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
 oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
 oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
 UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(oAuthConfig);
 var response = UrlFetchApp.getRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/latitude/v1/currentLocation");
 Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting some code of your attempt so that others can help better

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Code's been posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Latitude API [only supports OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/latitude/v1/using#auth), and Google Apps Script currently only supports OAuth 1.0a.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was the case. Thank you for your input

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we somehow add authentication data manually through HTTP headers in Apps Script?

Comment: Yes, using the headers advanced argument. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp#fetch

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to do it using the headers advanced argument? I can't figure it out by myself